# checkdnsrr Always returning True

Tags: php, dns

I am attempting to do some DNS pinging for a service I am building.

One of the services is to check a CNAME &/Or an A record for a URL passed, and return the boolean value

While it appears to work good for valid URL's, for invalid (and yes I've checked), it still is returning TRUE

## Code

```
    // Check DNS records
    private function DoDNSCheck($url){
        $url = $this->GetHost($url);
        echo '<pre>';
        $tr = dns_get_record($url, DNS_A + DNS_CNAME);
        print_r($tr);
        echo '</pre>';
        return (bool)(checkdnsrr($url, "CNAME") || checkdnsrr($url, "A"));  
    }
    private function GetHost($url){
        try{
            $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($url)); 
            return trim($parseUrl['host']);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

p.s. My servers DNS settings are retrieved from my router, which uses my ISP's DNS servers.  This issue still happens even if I try to use Google's and OpenDNS

I am even getting valid responses back from a `dns_get_record` check

With the functions above, I am getting:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [host] => www.sadfsdffoijoiuyiuoinsdf.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 10
        [type] => A
        [ip] => 69.16.143.25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [host] => www.sadfsdffoijoiuyiuoinsdf.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 10
        [type] => A
        [ip] => 198.105.251.24
    )

)
```

`bool(true)`

back from testing `DoDNSCheck('http://www.sadfsdffoijoiuyiuoinsdf.com');`

Comment: You are passing `$Address` to `GetHost()` but you are using and undefined `$URL`.  Maybe not the problem, but still.

Comment: It looks like your ISP has a DNS proxy that's redirecting all failed lookups to a search engine.

Comment: Those addresses go to search.charter.net

Comment: You can disable it at http://search.charter.net/prefs.php

Comment: I'll be a monkey's uncle.  Am I going to run across this issue once other users are using this service as well?  Can you update your answer to this...

Comment: and/or do you know if I can bypass that in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$Address = ((strpos($URL, "http://") !== false) || (strpos($URL, "https://") !== false)) ? 'http://' . $Address :  $Address;
```

You're using the wrong variable `$URL`, and the logic is backwards. It should be: